# MS Access calculation i cant figure out

Tags: ms-access

I need to create a table in MS Access like the following.
It's plain and simple, but I just cant figure it out.

For example

```
ID   debit      credit      balance
1    50                        50
2    20                        70
3                  30          40
4    15                        55      
5                  30          85
```

Thanks

Comment: Sorry the data came out wrong. will post again with an image

Comment: Typically, the balance field would be calculated in a query, not stored and updated within the table. What happens when a record is missed and then inserted later? You would have to modify all balance fields that occur after that missed entry.

Comment: Can't you code like balace[i]= debit[i+1]- credit[i+1] in a loop, except if ID=1 then balance[i]= debit[i]-credit[i]; Then data would be automatically updated, and debit and credit would be automatically filled by 0 so that the calc works out

Comment: I suppose you could but it woukd only work as a VBA function, not a table expression. If you're designing the table this way then Excel might be a better tool. Access doesn't have table triggers, so even if you wrote a function to calculate the balance, you'll have to run it manually. Plus normalization rules in databases usually bar storing calculations in a table. If you want the balance of ID 4, use a query that sums the debits and credits for ID's 1-4 and then find the difference. That's how Access is typically used.